# Add +1 Vote to MYSQL database on click

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, onclick, vote

So I'm making a quiz game that will show the percentage of people that agreed with you when an option is clicked. On click, results of previous players are displayed and your vote will be added to a database.

I have been trying to figure this out for quite some time now and after reading numerous posts and watching a lot of videos, it seems as though a combination of ajax and php is the way to go, I just can't seem to get it to play nice.

Here's what I've got. (With non-essential stuff removed to make it clearer.)

HTML

```
<div id="option1"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#option1').click(function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "clickvote.php",

        });
    }); 
});
```

I feel as though this is the problem. It seems as though jquery isn't actually calling the php file, am i missing something here, do i need to insert some form of data at this point rather than in the php?

PHP (clickvote.php)

```
<?php

include ('db_connect.php'); 
include ('getpageid.php');


$sql = "UPDATE questions SET votes1 = (votes1 + 1) WHERE id = {$pageid}";

mysqli_query($db,$sql);


?>
```

This PHP adds the vote and runs if I include it at top of the question page, however it adds the vote every time the page is loaded, not when option 1 is clicked, like i want it.

Let me know if you need any additional info.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Daniel

Comment: Are you getting any console error?

Comment: Nope, I'm not seeing any errors.

Comment: If you are not sure about if the pages is called or not. Open FireBug (or something similar), go to console, click persist and click on the div. See if the desired URL is called. You might find errors there as well

Comment: Can you open the network tab and check whether the ajax request is going?

Comment: Sanjay, When option 1 is clicked, it does seem to add clickvote.php to the list, however nothing is sent to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure of your php script path. Use your browser network it should return a success.

Try submitting the page id from the client side

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#option1').on('click', (function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "clickvote.php",
        data: {"page" : <?php echo $page_id ?>}
        });
    }); 
});
```

And then

```
<?php

include ('db_connect.php'); 
include ('getpageid.php');
$pageId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'page');

    $sql = "UPDATE questions SET votes1 = (votes1 + 1) WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param($pageId);
$stmt->execute();  

?>
```

Add prepared statements to make your query secure.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, I'm getting a syntax error for data: {"page" : <?php echo $page_id ?>}, saying it isnt expecting < or ?

Comment: I added this <?php echo $page_id ?> to add values to a javascript object but, this only works if the "template" file is .php and if you give a value to $page_id; In order to process the <?php //code ?> tags php iterpreter ask that the file is .php

Comment: Ok, I had the script as an external file, but I moved it to inside the php file  and I'm not getting the syntax errors anymore. It calls the clickvote.php but its showing errors for

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param($pageId);
$stmt->execute();  

The error says:

Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz\clickvote.php on line 9

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz\clickvote.php on line 9

Thanks again.

Comment: You need to define $mysql to be mysqli(). I suggest you to read http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php. First you need to create a connection with mysqli() and the you'll be able to properly use the database. If you are learning php rigth now, i suggest you to use PDO witch supports more databases than mysql. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. Your template files are rigth to be separated to your db script since $.post(),$.ajax() are ajax calls. Separating the two things is a good practice.

Comment: Got it working, I changed $mysqli to $db (from the 'db_connect.php' file.
Also I deleted the $stmt->bind_param($pageId); as it was giving errors but it seems to be working well now.

Thanks for all your help Yuri.